# Is there a way for Flex to access C++ functions from a DLL?

Tags: c++, apache-flex, dll, ria

I have an Adobe Flex application that needs to call C++ functions from a dll .

Since Flex apps execute within the browser, is there any way to do this ?

Comment: What is this "C/C++" you speak of?

Comment: I have been provided with library functions written in C which is used to perform some low level operations... the Flex app is a web based front-end ... Can this be done ? Im basically a web deveoper with not too much experience in C/C++... Flex here is Adobe Flex

Comment: What is "C/C++"? No such thing exists. C and C++ are two distinct, different languages. Please indicate which you are attempting to use.

Comment: What does this C++ dll do? Why do you need it for a web app?

Comment: The C++ dll actually interacts with a device.. The web based gui will be used to configure the device.. I know the best option would be a desktop app but I have been asked to develop a web browser based app..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went with [Firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home)

We created browser plugins with our existing C++ code, using Firebreath and it works great.
Firebreath creates both ActiveX and NPAPI plugins in a single .dll.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security issue, flash browser applications cannot call any client's desktop applications. But it becomes real if you're using AIR application. Are you?

Comment: No, we're not using AIR; however we may switch to AIR if I cannot find a solution to this problem. Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Did you already take a look at Alchemy?
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/

It will allow you to compile C or C++ code to an .swc that you can use in Flex

Keep in mind though that it has some limitations.
 
As the [docmentation](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aDocumentation%3aGetting_Started) states:

> Alchemy is primarily intended to be used with C/C++ libraries that
>   have few OS dependencies. The generated content is within the security
>   constraints of the AVM2, and cannot bypass Flash Player security
>   protections.

Though I'm not sure, I believe that it cannot handle (some) dlls either.

I know this is not a solid answer to your question but it could get you thinking in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! No, I didn't know about Alchemy. Will explore this possibility :)

Comment: It should be mentioned that Alchemy is still not 100% IMO.  It's mostly used for image manipulation and such and can be a bit buggy.